# CSS grid: Grid Items of various height

Tags: html, css

I want to make an admin dashboard which is kinda like this:[image] 
As you can see, the left items and right grid items have the same width, but the items differ in heights. The pie chart has a different height than the Area name grid item. 
What I tried so far is this, in which the first row has the same height. [image] 
The css I wrote:

```
//wrapping items with css grid
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, auto);
  gap: 8px;
}

//the pie chart
.grid-item-one {   
  background: #121619;
  color: white;
}

// the area name part
.grid-item-two {   
  background: #121619;
  color: white;
}
//the area list
.grid-item-three {
  background: #121619;
  color: white;
}
//the line chart
.grid-item-four {
  background: #121619;
  color: white;
}
```

I have tried to change the height of individual items but changing the height changes height of both grid items. How do I make the pie chart and area name part of different heights?

Comment: Basically you can't. What you need are two separate column containers.

Comment: @Paulie_D is right. You can start with a two-column grid. In the left-hand column you can place a grid with two rows and in the right-hand column you can place another grid with two rows.

Comment: @Rounin-StandingwithUkraine can you please type the css for that design? It would be easier to understand what you are trying to say

Comment: Pseudo-code: `<grid-with-two-cols><grid-with-two-rows><div class="row-1"></div><div class="row-2"></div></grid><grid-with-two-rows><div class="row-1"></div><div class="row-2"></div></grid></grid>`